# Can't retrieve a value on third Core Data migration

Tags: swift, core-data

I did 3 version of my Data Model:

[image]

I changed the names **solutis supposed to be solutis 2** and **solutis 2 supposed to be solutis**...

Solutis 2:

[image]

Solutis :

[image]
**xmlSendLead: Renaming ID = xml**

Solutis 3:

[image]
**statutSendSimulation: Renaming ID = statutEnvoieSendSimulation**

**statutSendLead: Renaming ID = statutEnvoieSendLead**

**dateSendSimulation: Renaming ID = dateEnvoieSendSimulation**

**dateSendLead: Renaming ID = dateEnvoieSendLead**

But when i'm migrating to the last from the previous version, I can't retrieve the xmlSendLead ...

I just added a data before doing my app update, I did a print on the first page:

```
            do {
                if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                    request = Leads.fetchRequest()
                } else {
                    request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Leads")
                }

                let results = try context.fetch(request)

                if results.count > 0 {
                    for item in results as! [Leads]{


                        print("results : item.id:\(item.id), item.statutSendLead:\(item.statutSendLead), item.dateSendLead:\(item.dateSendLead), item.xmlSendLead:\(item.xmlSendLead), item.contactWebId:\(item.contactWebId), item.statutSendSimulation:\(item.statutSendSimulation), item.dateSendSimulation:\(item.dateSendSimulation), item.xmlSendSimulation:\(item.xmlSendSimulation)")


                    }
                }

            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
```

results : item.id:Optional(1), item.statutSendLead:Optional(1), item.dateSendLead:Optional(2017-01-03 12:56:27 +0000), **item.xmlSendLead:nil**, item.contactWebId:Optional(120000139), item.statutSendSimulation:Optional(1), item.dateSendSimulation:Optional(2017-01-03 12:56:29 +0000), item.xmlSendSimulation:Optional("...>")